# Plesk PHP emails with laravel are not receiving DKIM signature

Tags: php, laravel, plesk, dkim

When I send email from the Round Cube web client, the email is signed signed with DKIM.

However when a website sends email via Laravel it is not signed with DKIM.

I'm sending two emails one with laravel notifications and one with mail.

Both don't receive a DKIM signature. I've turned on the signature settings in Plesk.

The question is how can I add my DKIM signature when sending emails using laravel.

```
OS: ‪Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS‬
Product: Plesk Obsidian 18.0.31 Update #1
```

my mail settings in laravel:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=test.****.store
MAIL_PORT=25 // I've tried 587 and 465 aswel. 
MAIL_USERNAME=order@***.store
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=order@****.store
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Rapio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by changing my mail driver to SMTP, this allowed my mails to add a DKIM signature